# How to install Ubuntu on part of the disk?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I have a new Laptop with 500GB hardisk size. I want to install 3 kind of Linux distribution. The first Linux will be Ubuntu.

Now, I want that the installation of Ubuntu will take over only 100 gb and I don't know how to do it.

I load the machine from the disk and I choose 'install Ubuntu' and I wait on the 'installation type' screen.

I chose the option of creating or resize the partition by myself - but I don't know what to do next.

please any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Comment: this is not same question as how to use manual...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been cross-posted: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269312/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-part-of-the-disk

Comment: You can use the same step and do it. If you need more clarification  ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assumed that there is no OS installed before. You can use GParted to split your HDD into several partitions:

1. Boot into your Ubuntu installer (USB/DVD)
2. Select Try Ubuntu without Installing
3. From the Dash, type 'GParted'. And you can start splitting your HDD from here.

Here is my disk partition looks like:
[I'm dual booting Windows and Ubuntu, also separate / and /home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCX2P.png)

Comment: thanks, but how to split the HDD that it will support 3 kind of Linux distribution.??

Comment: i split to 4 part - each part is ext4 with 70 giga - now i can't split to swap partition

Comment: just make new partition with 1 or 2 GB and format it as linux swap.
and ubuntu will automatically detect, than mount it as swap.